# Pass the regex test if there is only one space in the string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to get lines where there is a single space. I am currently doing it a different way because I still can't find a regex for it:

```
const line= "a b c";
/ {1}/.test(line)
```

- Expected: false
- Gets: true

I think this isn't syntactically good but am open to suggestions:

```
line.match(/ /g).length == 1
```

What should I look into?

Comment: The question is not clear. The `{1}` on the first regex does not have any effect this way but it makes me think that you do not want to accept multiple consecutive spaces. The second regex is just fine if you are interested only in the lines that contain exactly one space. What exactly do you need? Only one space on the entire line or multiple spaces are allowed but they must not be consecutive?

Answer (score 2):

The regular expression **/^[^\s]*\s[^\s]*$/** matches a string that contains only a single whitespace character.

**here is the code example:**

```
const regex = /^[^\s]*\s[^\s]*$/;

console.log(regex.test("ab c")); // true
console.log(regex.test("a b c")); // false
```

Comment: just realized you replied first, someone else did the same solution, i think it is the best way, but still quite acward

Answer (score 2):

Use the following regex test:

```
/^\S* (?=\S*)$/.test(line)
```

- `^\S*` - starts with optional non-spaces chars
- `(?=\S*)$` - positive lookahead, ensures that space is followed by any number of non-space chars (if occur) to the end of the string

Comment: interesting approach, still so convoluted that I may go ahead and just use `match.length`

Comment: @Minsky, note, `line.match(/ /g)` will return an array of all spaces (even if you don't need the whole) while `/^\S* (?=\S*)$/.test(line)` returns only single boolean result

Answer (score 2):

The question is not clear for me.
The `{1}` on the first regex does not have any effect this way but it makes me think that you do not want to accept multiple consecutive spaces. The second regex is just fine if you are interested only in the lines that contain exactly one space.

What exactly do you need?
Do you want the line to contain exactly one space?
Or multiple spaces are allowed, just to not be consecutive?

The following code snippet shows solutions for both questions:

```js
function test(input) {
  console.log({
    input,
    exactlyOne: (input.match(/ /g) ?? []).length === 1,
    noConsecutive1: / {2}/.test(input) === false,
    noConsecutive2: input.includes('  ') === false,
  });
}

// no consecutive spaces
test('a b c');
test('a b');
test('a');
test('a ');
test(' ');
test('');

// consecutive spaces; they all should report "exactlyOne: false, noConsecutive: false"
test('a b  c');
test('a  b');
test('aa  ');
test('  ');
```

The second search can be done without regexps. I cannot tell if it runs faster; for large inputs I think that the regexp is faster but I didn't check.

```js
if (input.includes('  ')) {
  console.log('two consecutive spaces found in the input');
}

I added it to the code snippet above.
```

Comment: i left it to give a queue of what I was trying even tjhough it was wrong. sorry. I actually did a similar code just to get it done, without seeing the solution, it is in the post actually. i guess there is no very good way

Comment: What do you think that is wrong with these solutions? The regex-es are expensive but this simple regex-es are linear and run fast. The regex for consecutive spaces does not even scan the entire input string but until it finds a match. The regex to count the number of spaces in the string can be written to stop when it finds the second space. Unless you have to process megabytes of text, you don't have to worry about their performance. Even then, I don't think there is a faster way to do it. Both can also be done without regex-es, searching for a string in the input string.

Answer (score 2):

Matching a string without newlines containing a single space

```
^\S* \S*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `\S*` Match optional non whitespace chars
- Match a single space
- `\S*` Match optional non whitespace chars
- `$` End of string

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/OqVxFb/1).

```js
const regex = /^\S* \S*$/;

[
  "a b c",
  "",
  "  ",
  " ",
  "a ",
  "a b"
].forEach(s => 
  console.log(`'${s}' --> ${regex.test(s)}`)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

`^[^\s]*\s[^\s]*$`

Explanation:

Start: `^`
Any number of non-spaces: `[^\s]*`
A single space `\s`
Any number of non-spaces (again): `[^\s]*`
End: `$`